# Java : Exception declaration while method overidding

Tags: java

```
class MyException extends Exception { }
class Tire {
    void doStuff() { }                                    //   #4
} 

public class Retread extends Tire {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Retread().doStuff();
    }
    // insert code here
    System.out.println(7/0);
}
```

And given the following four code fragments:

1. `void doStuff() {`
2. `void doStuff() throws MyException {`
3. `void doStuff() throws RuntimeException {`
4. `void doStuff() throws ArithmeticException {`

When fragments 1 - 4 are added, independently, at line 10, which are true? (Choose all that apply.)

- A. None will compile
- B. They will all compile
- C. Some, but not all, will compile
- D. All of those that compile will throw an exception at runtime
- E. None of those that compile will throw an exception at runtime
- F. Only some of those that compile will throw an exception at runtime

Answer: C and D are correct. **An overriding method cannot throw checked exceptions that are broader than those thrown by the overridden method.** However an overriding method can throw RuntimeExceptions not thrown by the overridden method. A, B, E,and Fare incorrect based on the above. (Objective 2.4)

I dont get what the BoldItalic marking is saying in this context. The overriding method(#4) doesnt throw any exception so how do we know if the one (in this case MyException) we add to the overridden method ( option 2) is broader than the overriding method. How does Arithmetic exception runs with no error. How is it not broader than the dont-know-which-exception in the overriding method.

Answer (score 5):

You override method `void doStuff() { }` which throws no exception with one of the options. So let's look at them, one by one:

```
void doStuff() { .. }
```

This one is okay, it throws no Exception like the base method.

```
void doStuff() throws MyException { .. }
```

This one won't compile. `MyException` is a checked exception because it extends `Exception` and the base method doesn't declare any checked exceptions at all.

```
void doStuff() throws RuntimeException { ... }
```

This will work, because `RuntimeException` is an unchecked exception.

```
void doStuff() throws ArithmeticException { ... }
```

This will work too, because `ArithmeticException` is a `RuntimeException`, so unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

void doStuff() { }

**is not throwing any checked exception .**

so the overriding method should also **not throw** any checked exception,

although it **can throw a runtime** exception(which need not to be mentioned be declaration).

Answer (score 0):

If the overridden method doesn't throw a checked exception, overriding method cannot throw, too. Throwing checked exceptions means nothing for compile time. You can throw any subclass of Runtime Exception without saying that this methods throws blah blah.

Runtime exceptions are generally bugs and development mistakes, such as nullpointerexception and arithmeticexception. You need to check those kind of pointers/values before sending them to a method. Otherwise, the program crashes.

Hovewer, you have nothing to do with checked exceptions except try/catch. They can have many causes such as connection error, file system error, operating system permissions, etc..